# Messages.app says "More results will be shown once Messages finishes indexing"

Tags: messages, indexing

As shown in the screenshot The Messages App is not finishing the indexing. I have not been able to find older conversations mentioning *gutter* :

[image: Screenshot of Messages with the notification at the bottom saying 'More results will be shown once Messages finishes indexing.']

I looked at a resource mentioning this error and have tried the top one: [Fixing "More results.." issue on macOS](https://becomethesolution.com/blogs/iphone/fix-more-photos-will-be-shown-once-messages-finishes-indexing-iphone#:%7E:text=More%20photos%20will%20be%20shown%20once%20Messages%20finishes%20indexing.,on%2Foff%20fixes%20indexing%20issues.)

> 1. Go to **Settings -> Apple ID -> iCloud -> and enable/disable Messages**. Some users report toggling iCloud messages on/off fixes indexing issues.

This change did not seem to have any effect (and it was done days ago).

There is a question here on [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-long-should-it-take-for-messages-in-big-sur-macos-11-4-to-finish-indexing.2302972/) but no answer.

Comment: Try logging out of your Apple ID from System Preferences, move all files in `/Library/Caches` and `~/Library/Caches` to the trash, reboot, empty the trash, log in to your Apple ID and try again

Comment: @Coder-256 This problem persisted on that computer and it continues on a completely new one as well.

Comment: Any resolution? Same issue here on latest macOS.